# Way to Filter by DB Field in Django using Class Views

Tags: python, html, django, sqlite

I tried to search for answers, but after a few days, I'm here asking:

I'm a beginner, making a todo list app - expanding on a tutorial I followed. Currently, it's filtering by user, which is fine, but I also want to filter by a field in the DB (list).

Models:

```
class ToDoList(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['created']


class Task(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    list = models.ForeignKey(ToDoList, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['complete']
```

View I'm trying to change:

```
class TaskList(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
model = Task
context_object_name = "tasks"


def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['tasks'] = context['tasks'].filter(user=self.request.user)
    context['count'] = context['tasks'].filter(complete=False).count

    search_input = self.request.GET.get('search-area') or ''

    if search_input:
        context['tasks'] = context['tasks'].filter(title__startswith=search_input)

    context['search_input'] = search_input

    return context
```

Also, is there a way to access the list variable in the html component, like here?

url:

```
path('tasks/<list>/create', TaskCreate.as_view(), name="task-create"),
```

html:

```
<a href="{% url 'tasks' 'task.list' %}">&#8592; Back</a>
```

Comment: is list a kwargs ? slug

Comment: Ask only **one** question per post. What's the difficulty you face filtering by `list`? `queryset.filter(list=todo_list_object)` or `queryset.filter(list_id=todo_list_id)`. You can get the id as a parameter from the url.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about the URL, that helped with the routing issues. For the filtering this did the trick (I hope): `context['tasks'] = context['tasks'].filter(list=self.kwargs['list'])`